# Torus Openlogin issue on next js

Tags: next.js

I have trying to login first using the torus openlogin with my gmail id and store private key along with some others data on database.
Now I am trying to connect torus wallet with same gmail id from web3 modal but again the torus login popup is opening and telling to again relogin.
Can any one please help me that is once i have got torus private key then without login how can i connect wallet through web3 modal.